# Moving one column value to another column - Pandas

Tags: pandas

This is the current code I use to move one column's value for a certain row to another column for the same row:

```
#Move 2014/15 column ValB to column ValA
df.loc[(df.Survey_year == 2014), 'ValA'] = df.loc[(df.Survey_year == 2014), 'ValB']
```

I do the same .loc[] again except on 2015 too. This works, but I don't
think this is the most efficient way to do it if I'm using a big
data frame with a lot of values to do this for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its similiar but much simpler logic. `np.where` allows you to define an if statement similar excel. If(x=y, do this is true, do this if false).

```
import numpy as np

df['ValA'] = np.where((df.Survey_year == 2014) | (df.Survey_year == 2015), df['ValB'], df['ValA'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting an error: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().    How would I fix this? EDIT: I just changed the or to | and it fixed it

Comment: Sorry, You're right, `or` is for python, not for comparing a series or dataframe. I'll edit

Answer (score 5):

**Clean Option**

```
mask = df.Survey_year.isin([2014, 2015])
df.loc[mask, 'ValA'] = df.loc[mask, 'ValB']
```

**Fast Option**

```
mask = np.in1d(df.Survey_year.values, [2014, 2015])
bloc = df.index.get_loc('ValB')
v = df.values
df.loc[mask, 'ValA'] = v[mask, bloc]
```